# Unable to pipe names of pinged computers that return false to test-netconnection

Tags: powershell, pipe, ping, powershell-5.0

I am trying to create a basic script that pulls a list of computer names from a text file, then pings them, and returns true or false. I then want to output the ones that returned false to a text file so I can know which ones are not responding.

the closest I have got to what I want to is below:

```
$workstations = Get-Content "workstation_list.txt"
$workstations | Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

However whenever I try to pipe the results anywhere all I get is the true or false.

How can I pass the original names that were in the $workstations array to show for all the ones that return false?

I have tried:

```
$workstations = Get-Content "workstation_list.txt"
$workstations | 
    Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel Detailed -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Select-Object computername, pingsucceeded | 
            if(pingsucceeded -eq False){write-output} else{continue}
```

with the following error:

```
pingsucceeded : The term 'pingsucceeded' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:11 char:144
+ ...  Select-Object computername, pingsucceeded | if(pingsucceeded -eq Fal ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pingsucceeded:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*
```

However I can't figure out how to only return the original name of the computer that is returning false when I ping it.

I then want to output it to a text file, however if I can't get it to pass the correct information to the screen It doesn't go to a file either.

Am I close or do I need to approach this a completely different way?

Thanks!

PS.this is one of my first times posting a question on stack overflow, if I need to provide information in a different way to make it easier for you to answer please provide constructive feedback so I can do better in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `PSCustomObject` to store your results like this:

```
$workstations = Get-Content "workstation_list.txt"
$Result =
foreach ($ComputerName in $workstations) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        Online = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet)
    }
}
$Result
```

This way you can use the variable `$Result` for further steps if needed. Output the successful ones for example

```
$Result | Where-Object -Property 'Online' -EQ -Value $true
```

Or filter the unsuccessful ones and output them to another file for example:

```
$Result | 
    Where-Object -Property 'Online' -EQ -Value $false |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName |
            Out-File -FilePath 'offline_workstation_list.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! Is there an easy way to make it output the original computer name that was pulled from the first text file? or would I just need to add on to the pipeline and use dnslookup or something like that?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm unsure if I understand this question. The computername is from the text file.

Answer (score 2):

There's some basic powershell that you need to learn.  You can't pipe to an if statement for one thing, but you can to foreach-object:

```
$workstations = Get-Content "workstation_list.txt"
$workstations |
Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel Detailed -WarningAction SilentlyContinue |
Select-Object computername, pingsucceeded |
foreach-object { if($_.pingsucceeded -eq $False){write-output $_} else{continue} }

ComputerName  PingSucceeded
------------  -------------
microsoft.com         False
```

Trying something with the call operator and $input.

```
echo hi | & { if ($input -eq 'hi') { 'yes' } }

yes
```

Comment: The problem I run into when using foreach-object is that it always says that "an empty pipe element is not allowed " when I try to pipe its output further. is there a way to get around this? I tried piping the above to |
Out-File -FilePath 'offline_workstation_list.txt' and it wasn't successful.

Comment: @JakeTheWandererSkolez You can't pipe from if, but you can pipe from foreach-object.

Comment: Thanks! I've been pretty stumped on that one. I didn't realize it was the if causing that.

Comment: @JakeTheWandererSkolez You can't pipe from the other form of foreach either `foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } `.  That throws people.